# RSA variable overflow through multiplication

Tags: matlab

I am trying to write a code for RSA Algorithm, my code produce (e,d,n) correctly, but the problem occurs when i calculate the cipher.
cipher = (plain^e) mod n.
because **(plain^e)** is a very large number.
the Calculator gives my correct result, while Matlab Don't. any one have ideas?

```
clc
e=61;
d=21;
n= 187;
Neuler=160;
Plain='ABCD';
Plain=uint64(Plain);
%%Encrypting Progress
for i=1:length (Plain);
Cypher(i)=mod((Plain(i)^e),n);
end
Numeri_Cypher=uint64(Cypher);
for i=1:length (Numeri_Cypher);
RPlain(i)=mod((Numeri_Cypher(i)^d),n);
end
Result=char(RPlain)
```

Comment: Can you show us the actual code you've tried?

Comment: Please edit your code into your original question

Comment: @Hesham you should edit your question and add the code there. By the way you should use a modular exponentiation algorithm instead of the built-in modulo.

Comment: @Suever ASCII for 'A' is 65
 (65^61) = 3.8700337745938424292737866010116e+110

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The built-in function `mod` can't deal with big integer. So I created a small implementation of the modular exponentiation, if you use this function you should have no problem.

```
function result = modpow(base,exp,m) 
   result = 1;
   while (exp > 0) 
      if bitand(exp,1) > 0
         result = mod((result * base),m);
      end
      exp = bitshift(exp,-1);
      base = mod(base^2,m);
   end
end
```

**EXAMPLE:**

With the built-in mod function:

```
mod(3^233249,4)

ans = 0 %incorrect result
```

With the modpow function

```
modpow(3,233249,4) 

ans = 1 %correct result
```